# Что выступает в роли загрузчика программы на языке C в Linux?

Tags: linux, c, loader

Перед выполнением программы ЦПУ её считывает с диска и загружает в первичную память загрузчик. Нагуглил, что это как-то связано с командой exec ядра в Linux. Будьте столь любезны, лбъясните, пожалуйста, подробнее в деталях процесс загрузки программы, скомпилированной из кода на языке Си с помощью 'gcc main.c' в Linux x64?

Comment: https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/linux-syscall-4.html

Comment: хотя это и легкая форма наркомании, но мне эта статья на хабре понравилась https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/753506/

Comment: кратко и неумно - ваша программа есть подпрограмма, можно даже функцией обозвать, которую эпизодически подключает на запуск операционная система, как самая главная программа на вашем компьютере. для этого "эту функцию" надо считать в оперативную память на свободные места, определить адрес памяти для старта "этой функции", так как адрес размещения выделяет главная программа и запустить "эту функцию" передав процессору адрес выполнения и переход (jump) на стартовый адрес "этой функции" - вашей программы.